# Nonempty subset of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Show that if $G$ is a finite group, then a nonempty subset $H$ is a subgroup iff $\forall h,h'\in H$, $h*h'\in H$.

I have broken it up into two parts, but don't really know how to proceed. I haven't worked with subgroups before and am kind of lost how to use the definition.

i) Say $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Show $h*h' \in H$.

ii) Say $h*h' \in H$. Show $H$ is a subgroup.

I think part i) holds just from the definition of a subgroup. Is that correct?

Comment: What is your definition of subgroup?

Comment: If $H$ is a nonempty subset of G, H is a subgroup if:

i. $\forall h,h' \in H$, $h*h' \in H$
ii. $\forall h \in H$, $h^-1 \in G$ is also $\in H$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about part (i); it is part of the definition of a (sub) group.

As for part (ii), let $h \in H$ and consider the sequence of powers of $h$; they are all contained in $H$:

$\{h^i \mid i \in \Bbb N \} = \{h^1 = h, h^2, h^3, \ldots, h^{k - 1}, h^k, h^{k + 1}, \ldots \} \subset H; \tag 1$

since $H$ is finite, this sequence must begin to repeat itself at some point; that is, there must be $m, n \in \Bbb N$ with $n > m$ and $h^n = h^m$; then
$h^{n - m} = e$, the identity element of $G$; this shows that $e \in H$; also, we have

$hh^{n - m - 1} = h^{n - m} = e, \tag 2$

which shows that $h^{n - m - 1} \in H$ is the inverse element of $h$.  Thus $H$ not only contains the identity element $e$ of $G$, but also the inverse of each of its (i.e., $H$'s) elements.  So $H$ must be a subgroup of $G$.